# How do I detect a button release?

Tags: c, arduino, detection, arduino-uno, atmega

I am new to arduino and its programming. For my project I use the voltage detection of the pressed button. When a button is pressed, the variable "keypressed" is assigned the value of the pressed button. After releasing the button, the variable "keyreleased" must be assigned to the value of the released button.

```
  int analogVal = analogRead(A0);              //read analog voltage value from pin A0
  if (analogVal < 325) keypressed = instrkey;
  if (analogVal < 300) keypressed  = keyB4;
  if (analogVal < 275) keypressed  = keyA4s;
  if (analogVal < 250) keypressed  = keyA4;
  if (analogVal < 225) keypressed  = keyG4s;
  if (analogVal < 200) keypressed  = keyG4;
  if (analogVal < 175) keypressed  = keyF4s;
  if (analogVal < 150) keypressed  = keyF4;
  if (analogVal < 125) keypressed  = keyE4;
  if (analogVal < 100) keypressed  = keyD4s;
  if (analogVal < 75) keypressed  = keyD4;
  if (analogVal < 50) keypressed  = keyC4s;
  if (analogVal < 25) keypressed  = keyC4;
  if (analogVal > 1000) keyreleased = nokey;
```

In this code we need to build the function of button release detection.

I tried using the if construction, but it didn't work. Because the first condition breaks before the next one is fulfilled.

```
if (analogVal < 325) keypressed = instrkey; {
    if (keypressed != instrkey) keyreleased = instrkey;
  }
```

And when I decided to use loops, all the code stopped and did not respond to button signals. This happened with both "for" and "while".

Comment: That's a weird kind of keyboard you have there. Can you tell us what hardware that is?

Comment: The second code snippet doesn't make sense. It has weirdly placed `{}` and it isn't clear what it is supposed to express. In general, if I extrapolate correctly your system workings from the code,  it looks like you want a simple `if (analogVal > 1000) { keyreleased = keypressed; keypressed = nokey;}`

Comment: It seems at most one key can be pressed at any time, so store the `keypressed_old` value. After detecting the currently pressed key, do `if(keypressed != keypressed_old) keyreleased = keypressed_old;`.

Comment: What happens if `analogVal` is in the range [325, 1000]?

Comment: @EugeneSh. These are my attempts to complete the task. And since I am inexperienced, I get strange things.

Comment: @Neil Nothing will change. I have edited and added a photo of the connection. There you can see that there are no more than 12 buttons.

Comment: @nielsen I'm not quite sure how I can keep the value.


`int analogVal = analogRead(A0);
  if (analogVal < 325) {keypressed = instrkey, keypressed_old =  instrkey;}
  if (analogVal < 300) {keypressed = keyB4, keypressed_old = keyB4;}
  ... ... ... // and so on with the other lines
  if (analogVal < 25) {keypressed = keyC4, keypressed_old = keyC4;}
  if (analogVal > 1000) keypressed = nokey, keyreleased = nokey;
  if(keypressed != keypressed_old) keyreleased = keypressed_old;`


'keypressed' works fine, but 'keypressed_old' sets 'nokey' and does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to get keypressed and keyreleased :

```
int lastKey=nokey; //assume keys are integer
void loop() {
  int analogVal = analogRead(A0);              //read analog voltage value from pin A0
  if (analogVal < 325) keypressed = instrkey;
  if (analogVal < 300) keypressed  = keyB4;
  if (analogVal < 275) keypressed  = keyA4s;
  if (analogVal < 250) keypressed  = keyA4;
  if (analogVal < 225) keypressed  = keyG4s;
  if (analogVal < 200) keypressed  = keyG4;
  if (analogVal < 175) keypressed  = keyF4s;
  if (analogVal < 150) keypressed  = keyF4;
  if (analogVal < 125) keypressed  = keyE4;
  if (analogVal < 100) keypressed  = keyD4s;
  if (analogVal < 75) keypressed  = keyD4;
  if (analogVal < 50) keypressed  = keyC4s;
  if (analogVal < 25) keypressed  = keyC4;
  if (analogVal > 1000) keypressed  = nokey;
  //if (analogVal > 1000) keyreleased = nokey;

  if (lastKey != keypressed) {
    keyreleased=lastKey;
    lastKey=keypressed;
  }
}
```

example :

at prog start, lastkey=nokey and keypressed=nokey.

1- press keyG4   : keypressed change from nokey to keyG4, keyreleased stay equal to nokey and lastkey become equal to keyG4

2- release keyG4 : keypressed change from keyG4 to nokey, keyreleased become keyG4 and lastkey become nokey.

etc....

Comment: With your code, the value of 'keyreleased' does not want to change. While 'lastkey' takes the value 'keypressed'  when the button is pressed. I tried changing some values, but it didn't help.

Comment: It all worked after I took the variable declaration out of the 'void'. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is what my working code looks like.

```
byte nokey = 255;
byte keypressed = nokey;
byte keyreleased = nokey;
byte lastKey = nokey;

#define keyC4   0
#define keyC4s  1
#define keyD4   2
#define keyD4s  3
#define keyE4   4
#define keyF4   5
#define keyF4s  6
#define keyG4   7
#define keyG4s  8
#define keyA4   9
#define keyA4s 10
#define keyB4  11

#define nokey 255
#define instrkey 254

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  
  int analogVal = analogRead(A0); // Read analog voltage value from pin A0
  if (analogVal < 325) keypressed = instrkey;
  if (analogVal < 300) keypressed = keyB4;
  if (analogVal < 275) keypressed = keyA4s;
  if (analogVal < 250) keypressed = keyA4;
  if (analogVal < 225) keypressed = keyG4s;
  if (analogVal < 200) keypressed = keyG4;
  if (analogVal < 175) keypressed = keyF4s;
  if (analogVal < 150) keypressed = keyF4;
  if (analogVal < 125) keypressed = keyE4;
  if (analogVal < 100) keypressed = keyD4s;
  if (analogVal < 75) keypressed = keyD4;
  if (analogVal < 50) keypressed = keyC4s;
  if (analogVal < 25) keypressed = keyC4;

  if (lastKey != keypressed) {
    keyreleased=lastKey;
    lastKey=keypressed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pulling a value out of the ADC from the free-running main loop with completely random real-time characteristics is the wrong approach.

- Even though you are reading keys through an ADC, they still come with a signal bounce which needs to be "de-bounced". Failing to do so will result in incorrectly read buttons.
- Additionally, SA ADC always have a built-in fluctuation when you happen to give it a voltage that sits just between two raw values. Lets say that you happen to give it a voltage corresponding to the value 299.5. It is not an exact match, so the successive approximation might pick the value 299 this ADC cycle and 300 the next cycle.
- Additionally, there is always EMI and general noise that can be picked up from cables, particularly so if using skunky breadboards etc with no proper ground plane.

---

To counter all these problems, you need to perform multiple measurements before you can come to a conclusion regarding which key if any that was pressed.

One way to do so is to run a cyclic timer executing for example once every 5ms. At the start of the timer ISR, grab the last ADC value read. Store the value. Then in the same ISR, check the last 3 reads or so to conclude which button that was pressed. You can make a condition that the ADC value must remain within the same interval for these 3x5 = 15ms or you'll discard it.